# "Can't parse 'pt'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type." PointPolygon error

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting this error when I tried to use OpenCV for a project.

```
  File "/Users/alex/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/alex/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 51, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/CLAM/CLAM/wsi_core/WholeSlideImage.py", line 481, in process_coord_candidate
    if WholeSlideImage.isInContours(cont_check_fn, coord, contour_holes, ref_patch_size):
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/CLAM/CLAM/wsi_core/WholeSlideImage.py", line 345, in isInContours
    if cont_check_fn(pt):
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/CLAM/CLAM/wsi_core/util_classes.py", line 86, in __call__
    if cv2.pointPolygonTest(self.cont, points, False) >= 0:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'pointPolygonTest'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

What does this error mean? I'm quite new to python so please educate me. Thank you!

Here's the project link

https://github.com/mahmoodlab/CLAM#wsi-segmentation-and-patching

Comment: You should add more details (and directly on the question). Your problem is in `pointPolygonTest`, so you should write the error stack with also such line. or it is just your data which has not just numbers but also the string 'pt'.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi Thank you for the reminder, just edited the error stack.

Comment: Possibly pointPolygonTest is looking for *integers*, and perhaps you are passing in float values? (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851320/cant-parse-center-sequence-item-with-index-0-has-a-wrong-type ).

Answer (score 3):

**pt** parameter may be a tuple, I solve this problem via the following snippet, hope this can help you.

```py
# if pt is list type point (x, y)
pt = tuple([int(round(pt[0]) ), int(round( pt[1] )) ])
if cv2.pointPolygonTest(contour, pt, False) == 0:
    print(pt)
```

my opencv-python version is : **opencv-python==4.5.3.56**

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem and solve it by downgrading opencv version to 4.5.1.48

Reference from this website:
https://pythonrepo.com/repo/opencv-opencv-python-computer-vision

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem too and I needed to use opencv-version to 4.5.3.

Here the problem comes from.

```
iterable = [(coord, contour_holes, ref_patch_size[0], cont_check_fn) for coord in coord_candidates]
```

The first index of "iterable" has a numpy array to hold the contour coordinates. However, these coordinates are keep as numpy dtype with numpy.uint32. If we are using new versions of opencv-python we have to convert it to int as python data type.

I fixed this issue simply like here,

```
iterable_new = []

for i in iterable:

    iterable_line = [np.uint32(i[0][0]).item(), np.uint32(i[0][1]).item()], i[1], i[2], i[3]
    iterable_new.append(iterable_line)
```

Update the "iterable" below with the new one.

```
results = pool.starmap(WholeSlideImage.process_coord_candidate, iterable)
```