# Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Tags: python, opencv

I have written the following code in OpenCV in V.S. Code on Mac. I have assigned (pts1) pixel values of certains points in the image (img). But, when I try to circle the points I am getting this error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
cv.circle(img, (pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1]), 5, (0,0,255), cv.FILLED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'circle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Any suggestions on how can I resolve this issue? Do let me know if you have any concerns regarding the code. Thanks for the help!

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Cards Image

img = cv.imread('Images/cards.jpg')

cv.imshow('Cards Image', img)

# Step 1. Note down the pixel value of all the 4 corners from the image

pts1 = np.float32([[657,122],[738,235],[478,249],[559,362]])

print(pts1)

cv.circle(img, (pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1]), 5, (0,0,255), cv.FILLED)

# i = 0

# for i in range(4):
#     cv.circle(img, (pts1[i][0], pts1[i][1]), 5, (0,0,255), cv.FILLED)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your points are integers expressed as floats. The values for the circle center (x,y) need to be integers not floats. So convert them to integers, i.e. int(pts1[0][1]) etc.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem is just parsing the `(x, y)` or the `(pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1])` to integers you just have to do the following `(int(pts1[0][0]), int(pts1[0][1]))` in the `circle` function

Comment: for numpy arrays, simply use `arr.astype(int)`

Answer (score -7):

Sol:

```
cv2.line(img, (**int**(corners_int[0, 0]), **int**(corners_int[0, 1])), (**int**(corners_int[3, 0]), **int**(corners_int[3, 1])), (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: Please don't provide code only answers. Is there anything you can explain in your answer that might improve the OP's understanding of your proposed solution?